# Using pathUntil method

Tags: scala, graph

I have the following definitions of a Scala graph:

```
trait NodeType 

case class SourceNode() extends NodeType
case class SinkNode() extends NodeType
case class SimpleNode() extends NodeType

case class Node(className: String, method: String, stmt: String, line: Int, nodeType: NodeType)

var svg = collection.mutable.Graph.empty[Node,DiEdge]
```

When I call the `pathUntil` method in a node of the svg graph, I get the following compilation error using sbt:

```
value pathUntil is not a member of scalax.collection.mutable.Graph[br.unb.cic.soot.graph.Node,scalax.collection.GraphEdge.DiEdge]#NodeT
```

A similar error also occurs when I try to use the method `pathTo`. Curiously, the auto-completer of my IDE finds this `pathUntil` operation. I wonder: is it possible that the scala compiler is not properly inferring the type of a node graph? Should I import a specific library or set any compiler option for fixing this?

Comment: Empty case classes should be case objects. Apart from that, the standard library doesn't have a `Graph` class, so it may be useful to mention the library you are using as well to a link to it.

Comment: oh... thanks. I am using scala-graph (http://www.scala-graph.org/)

Comment: In demo https://github.com/scala-graph/scala-graph/blob/8f8811e67cd8606b5d705cc086cd46ae19c1f1da/core/src/test/scala/demo/Traversing.scala there is `pathUntil` used. Maybe try some imports from there e.g.: `import scalax.collection.edge.Implicits._`